# Binding for custom control works in GridView but not in FormView

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, formview

I am turning some paper forms into web forms, and one of my requirements is to have a Yes/No group of checkboxs that can also track if no selection has been made. So I can't just use a single CheckBox bound to a bit field in Sql Server because that doesn't track whether the user has ignored the field or not.

To solve my problem I wrapped two checkboxes into an ASCX control. I then created a public Checked property in my ASCX control. From this property I returned "True" if the true checkbox was checked, "False" is the false checkbox was checked, and an empty string if neither checkbox was checked.

When I put this control in a GridView and bind it to a bit field using the GridView SqlDataSource everything works perfectly. When I bind the same control in a FormView though the FormView's update sets untouched controls to False. I stepped through my controls logic and it is passing the empty string correctly, so it seems that the FormView is overriding the value before sending it to the stored procedure.

Is there a way to make this work in the FormView or am I going to have to refactor to use something like an int field to track the three options: 0=no selection, 1=true, 2=false, or something like that? I've provided the code for my ASCX control below for reference.

```
public partial class controls_yesNoCheck : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public string Checked
    {
        get
        {
            if (ckbNo.Checked)
                return "false";
            if (ckbYes.Checked)
                return "true";
            else
                return "";
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == "")
            {
                ckbNo.Checked = false;
                ckbYes.Checked = false;
            }
            else if (value == "True" || value == "true")
            {
                ckbYes.Checked = true;
                ckbNo.Checked = false;
            }
            else
            {
                ckbNo.Checked = true;
                ckbYes.Checked = false;
            }
        }
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void noChecked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ckbYes.Checked = false;
    }

    protected void yesChecked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ckbNo.Checked = false;
    }
}
```

Edit:
The front-end of the control looks so, I left the CheckChanged methods out of the previous code block since their functionality doesn't impact this problem.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="yesNoCheck.ascx.cs" Inherits="controls_yesNoCheck" %>

<asp:CheckBox ID="ckbYes" runat="server" Text="Yes" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="yesChecked" />
<asp:CheckBox ID="ckbNo" runat="server" Text="No" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="noChecked" />
```

Comment: Have you tried using a nullable bool type (bool?).  That will give three options and then you can check hasvalue on whether to set the bit column to DBNull.

Comment: @JonRaynor - I tried the nullable bool type and when a NULL value is read from the database and sent to my control as shown above the site crashes.

Comment: You will need some code to check to see if the value is null in the database when reading the data, something like if (record["YesNoFlag"] == DBNull.Value then  //Set nullable type to not have a value...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who may stumble upon this later, @randomben and @jonraynot are probably barking up the "best practice" tree, but I was able to fix my problem by changing my stored procedure.

It might not be the greatest solution ever, but here it is. I changed the parameter in my update stored procedure from a bit field to nvarchar(5), then using the following CASE statement (simplified to get the point across)

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET bit_column_name = CASE 
    WHEN @bit_column_name = 'True' THEN 'True'
    WHEN @bit_column_name = 'False' THEN 'False'
    ELSE NULL
    END
```

With that change to the stored procedure I didn't have to make any changes to the code I posted before.

Answer (score 2):

Have you thought about using [nullable types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)?

You could then have much simpler code and it would match to the DB better since SQL  Server has a nullable bit type.  Something like this should work:

```
public bool? Checked {get; private set;}
public void setChecked(String value)
{
    if (value == "")
       _checked = null;
    else if (value.ToLower() == "true")
       _checked = true;
    else
       _checked = false;
}
```

Based off of where you are saying the error is not occurring and your code above, I would bet that there is some issue with your conversion from string to int for insertion into the database.  Again, switching to the above code should resolve that issue.

Comment: I had not considered it b/c I am not familiar with nullable types. I'm getting compilation errors with your code but I'll work on it and report back. Thanks

Comment: Justin C - Try out my modified code.  I made two mistakes because I was typing too quickly.  The modified code should work much better.  The reason for the move to the setChecked is that you need to convert a string into a Boolean and you cannot do that on a property unless you also want the get to return a string which is not ideal.

Comment: @RandomBen - that compiles and looks closer to what I need, but still not working. Is there something missing in the Checked get and set?

Comment: @JustinC You will not be able to set Checked directly because the set method is private, hence the need for the setChecked() method.  However, if you are still having a problem then your issue is either in your state, ie, how the Checked field's state is being saved or it is in how you post the data to the database.  Your best bet is to  debug your code and see what the value of Checked is when it is sent to the method or in the method that puts it in the database.  If it is correct there, then the issue is with how you save it to the database. In which case, we will need to see that code.

Comment: @RandomBen - With the code I posted before, I am binding it in FormViews and GridViews with Checked='<%# Bind("db_bit_column") %>'. As I mentioned in the question, this approach works perfectly in a GridView, but in a FormView it turns the no interaction state into 'False'. That happens after the empty string value leaves my control. So if my control is in the no interaction state, it sends an empty string, which in a GridView writes NULL to the DB and in a FormView writes False for some reason.